# Can I "transfer" my Windows 7 license to a virtual machine running on the same computer?

Tags: windows-7, virtual-machine, license

I've read [the blog post](http://blog.superuser.com/2011/04/06/microsoft-licencing-transferring-windows-to-another-computer/) on license transfer, but I'm not clear in the case where I already have a licensed, activated copy of Windows 7 running on my PC but want to move that license to a VM running in Ubuntu *on the same PC*. Am I allowed?

Comment: you could always package up your whole hard drive as an image, and then boot the VM from that? would that work? possibly some hardware issues i guess... but if the whole point is just to move your working windows env out of the way to make room for ubuntu...

Answer (score 39, accepted):

Section 3d of both the OEM and Retail licenses of the ones I checked (Windows 7 Professional and Windows 7 Home Premium) state:

> d. Use with Virtualization Technologies. Instead of using the software directly on the licensed 
>   computer, you may install and use the software within only one virtual (or otherwise emulated) 
>   hardware system on the licensed computer.

Since the poster's machine is the licensed computer and will be running Ubuntu as a host OS with Windows running in a single VM on a virtual hardware system on the same licensed computer, then according to this, it's okay.

https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/useterms

Comment: You can also find a copy of your license under the activation details area in your Control Panel which may differ. In the above provided link, the license for pre-installed Windows 7 Professional states that any license that comes with your installation superceeds it.

Comment: You'll still need to call them to manually activate it.

Comment: In the main hypervisors you can passthrough the BIOS info so an OEM copy from a main manufacturer will automatically activate.

Answer (score 4):

You're allowed to do this if Microsoft allows you to do this. This sounds like a non-answer but keeping this in mind helped me move my OEM license to a VM, free and clear, with the help of Microsoft support.

Get your product key first from the original OEM-install of Windows by entering `wmic path softwarelicensingservice get OA3xOriginalProductKey`at an administrator command prompt.

Then move the OEM Windows to a VM somehow (e.g. via VMware's free [vCenter Converter](https://my.vmware.com/web/vmware/evalcenter?p=converter)), enter `slui 4` at the command prompt, and follow the instructions for activating over the phone. You may need to call back a few times to get a cooperative support associate but it's worth the effort.

Answer (score 0):

OEM means licensed to 1 specific computer, Retail means licensed to 1 computer at any time. A VM is considered a seperate computer, you can transfer a retail license, but not an OEM one. This is why retail copies cost more than OEM ones.

Comment: So to specifically answer the OP's question, if you have a retail license you are allowed to transfer it, but if you are using a OEM license you are not allowed to transfer it.

Comment: You need to check the *actual OEM license terms*. See @dawnBenton answer above.

Comment: So I guess this answer is incorrect and should be removed.

Comment: The oem version can be used in a VM but only run on top of the original hardware.

Comment: @StéphaneGourichon I think you misunderstood either my comment or DawnBenton's answer because they are in agreement.

Comment: @JamesRyan oh, you're right. Deleting my wrong comment.