# Can I use Syntext Serna (Abandonware) commercially?

Tags: copyright

The Syntext company is no longer around, but the XML editor they created back in 2009 is still available from Tucows and other sites.

Version 4.2 states "Serna Free is intended for personal use at home, documenting open-source projects, education, and other non-commercial uses."

I want to use it commercially. Are the terms of use still enforceable?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because licensing advice is off-topic on Super User.

Answer (score 3):

> Serna Free is intended for personal use at home, documenting open-source projects, education, and other non-commercial uses

I downloaded the Mac version and checked the included license file. It includes the following sentence in the section concerning Serna Free (emphasis mine):

> Upon your acceptance of this EULA, Syntext freely grants you a personal
>   non-exclusive, non-transferable, limited license to use the Software on your
>   computer for personal *or business purposes*.

Assuming it's the same in the Windows version, there should be no problem.

---

Additionally, it seems Serna Free has been open-sourced as GPL [on GitHub](https://github.com/ydirson/serna-free), so if you're able to build it (seems not quite straightforward, but who knows?), [you can use it for whatever you like](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_General_Public_License#Use_of_licensed_software).

Comment: Whether any of this still applies as the company isn't around anymore (answering the question as stated) would probably be out of scope of this site -- luckily, there's an answer that IMO is within scope, given other questions like [this one](https://superuser.com/questions/821251/can-i-transfer-my-windows-7-license-to-a-virtual-machine-running-on-the-same-c).